# MAMP Apache Won't Start with Virtual Host for SimpleSAMLphp

Tags: apache, mamp, simplesamlphp

I'm attempting to configure simpleSAMLphp within a MAMP/Apache environment on Windows 10 and below is my httpd-vhosts.conf file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName localhost
    DocumentRoot C:/MAMP/htdocs
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName simplesamlphp
    DocumentRoot C:/MAMP/htdocs/pro-dashboard

    Alias /simplesaml C:/MAMP/simplesamlphp/www

    <Directory C:/MAMP/simplesamlphp/www>
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

And here is my /etc/hosts file:

```
# localhost name resolution is handled within DNS itself.
#   127.0.0.1       localhost
#   ::1             localhost

# Virtual Hosts
    127.0.0.1   simplesamlphp
```

Apache starts via MAMP totally fine without including this httpd-vhosts.conf file in my httpd.conf file, but as soon as its included, Apache will not start so the issue appears to be with httpd-vhosts.conf.  No errors are shown in the apache_error.log file.  My Apache version is 2.2 so I believe my Directory directives in my second VirtualHost are correct.

I've tried double quoting the DocumentRoot's, directory paths etc, and also tried backslashes over forward slashes.  I spent most of yesterday trying to figure this out while scouring the web but nothing I found has made this work.

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Try this modified config
The path in Directory header same as DocumentRoot!

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName localhost
    DocumentRoot C:/MAMP/htdocs
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName simplesamlphp
    DocumentRoot C:/MAMP/htdocs/pro-dashboard

    Alias /simplesaml C:/MAMP/simplesamlphp/www

    <Directory C:/MAMP/htdocs/pro-dashboard>
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Thanks, @Adam P.   But the reason for that directory directive is so that the `simplesamlphp/www` directory is available as it is placed outside the `htdocs` dir.

Answer (score 0):

So oddly enough, taking out what I had in httpd-vhosts.conf and simply putting it in my httpd.conf file makes Apache start back up.